# android fragemnt get destroyed - how to keep alive?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

i have a question about fragments in android.
when i call another fragment, the main fragment get destroyed (its replaced by other fragment).
so if i have a music player that playing in one fragment when i calling play list fragment the music stops.
is there any way to keep alive the first fragment like in Google "play music" ?

its my code for replacing fragment content:

```
 fragment.setArguments(args);
       FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
       frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_place, fragment)
               .commit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Service` in the background which plays the music.

Then the UI is completely separated from the playback of music. So audio can also play when your app is not in the foreground.

Comment: but how i will update my ui fragment when song is playing? i mean the title of the song in example, because when i go back to my first fragment it will load the default layout

Comment: You could retrieve the information from your Service

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a service which most music playing apps do, or run your playing music code in the activity rather than in the fragment.